# How to sort this list by the highest score?

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have this list

```
data_list = [['Bob', [4]], ['Jimmy', [8]], ['Reece', [8]], ['Zerg', [5]]]
```

How do I sort it so prints the highest number first like;

```
['Jimmy',[8]],['Reece',[8]], ['Zerg', [5]],['Bob',[4]]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) function with the `key` parameter to look at the 2nd item, and `reverse` set to `True` to sort in descending order.

```
>>> sorted(data_list, key = lambda i : i[1], reverse = True)
[['Jimmy', [8]], ['Reece', [8]], ['Zerg', [5]], ['Bob', [4]]]
```

Comment: Thanks thats a big help :)

Comment: alternatively, avoid the `lambda` with `operator.itemgetter`: `sorted(data_list, key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)`